# Encrypted value is not matching between java and oracle 12c

Tags: java, encryption, oracle12c

The encrypted value from Java from the given code

---

```
public static String encrypt(String data, String sessionuser) throws Exception {

   sessionuser = "HVQKcI6yo425a4d6";
   data = "HelloWorld!";

    byte[] keyValue = sessionuser.getBytes();
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");

    System.out.println(key);

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(data.getBytes());

    String encryptedValue = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(encVal);
    return encryptedValue;
}
```

---

The returned encryptedValue = **48yKDDmHCgotgbTpy3FRag**

### The encrypted value from the oracle 12c code is

```
SELECT (DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT
    (
       src => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW ('HelloWorld!'),
       typ =>    4096 + 256 +4,--4356, --encryption_type / AES_CBC_PKCS5 = ENCRYPT_AES + CHAIN_CBC + PAD_PKCS5
       key => UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('HVQKcI6yo425a4d6')--, encryption_key 
    ))
from dual;
```

---

output : E3CC8A0C39870A0A2D81B4E9CB71516A
After converting it from hex to base 64 : **48yKDDmHCgotgbTpy3FRag==**

Please let us know how to get the matching value between java and oracle.

Thanks

Comment: they are the same, just the base64 padding is different. right?

Comment: that is what we are not sure about. We want encrpted value in java and in oracle DB should be same

Comment: According to the oracle doc you could use [`UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_encode.htm#i999460) to encode the result of the DB to base64. Also note that in Java the `Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString` does not apply padding and uses the URL-safe base64 alphabet. You might want to use `Base64.encodeBase64String` to get the normal Base64 alphabet in java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jdk's base 64 encoder. It will preserve the '=' padding at the end.

```
String encryptedValue = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encVal);
```

It is just the difference in encoding with or without padding. The result is the same with zero to two equal sign at the end.

Comment: Actually, we are looking to keep the value coming from java as it is and need to make oracle 12c value compatible to that of java.

Comment: then you should have posted this question in a db forum :)